# Detect when a sequence of rows with contiguous 1/TRUE starts and ends R dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I need to detect the positions of rows of a variable `ice` ordered by another variable `day` which have 5 or more contiguous rows with `TRUE`

```
da <- tibble(day=1:365,ice=runif(365)>.8)
da$ice[140:143] <- TRUE
da$ice[150:156] <- TRUE
da$ice[180:184] <- TRUE
```

I added some noise to the data.frame but I need to detect the first `day` of the first block of days when there are 5 or more `TRUE`s on the `ice` variable and the last day for the last block, In the example that would be `day` 150 and `day` 184.

I would use loops like this

```
first_day <- 0
for(i in 1:(nrow(da)-5))
{
  if(sum(da$ice[i:(i+5)])==5){

    first_day <- da$day[i]
    print(first_day)
  } 
}
```

This is only a first attempt not working very well, but can't figure out how to do that using dplyr or base R without loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We create a grouping variable based on the `run-length-id` of 'ice', then `filter` the rows where `all` values of 'ice' are TRUE and the number of rows (`n()`) is greater than or equal to 5, `ungroup` and `slice` the first and last row

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
da %>% 
   group_by(grp = rleid(ice)) %>%
   filter(all(ice), n() >= 5) %>%
   ungroup %>%
   slice(c(1, n()))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 2 x 3
#    day ice     grp
#  <int> <lgl> <int>
#1   150 TRUE     46
#2   184 TRUE     58
```

---

Or an option with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
range(setDT(da)[, day[all(ice) & .N >= 5], rleid(ice)]$V1)
#[1] 150 184
```

Answer (score 1):

In base R using `rle` you can do :

```
with(rle(da$ice), {
  #Get index where ice is TRUE for 5 or more time
  inds <- which(values & lengths >= 5)
  #Get the corresponding day value
  vals <- cumsum(lengths)[range(inds)]
  #vals has starting index of first and last TRUE
  #Since we want the end index of first TRUE we adjust it 
  #based on it's length.
  vals[1] <- vals[1] + lengths[inds[1]] -1
  vals
})

#[1] 150 184
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit experimental:

```
tmp <- as.numeric(da$ice)
min(
which(c(tmp, 0, 0, 0, 0) +
        c(0, tmp, 0, 0, 0) +
        c(0, 0, tmp, 0, 0) +
        c(0, 0, 0, tmp, 0) +
        c(0, 0, 0, 0, tmp) >= 5) - 4
)
```